# Create alert when Kubernetes pods "Does not have minimum availability" on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, metrics

I want to set alert policy for when there isn't enough pods in my Deployment. There are tons of metrics in Kubernetes which I am not sure which to use.

Just choosing CPU utilisation might work as a hack, but that might still miss cases where container crashes and backs of - I am not too sure.

Edit: hack above doesn't really work - perhaps I should check at requested cores?

[image]

Edit 2: adding image to answer comment
[image]

Comment: Can u please provide a detailed log ( expanding the nested fields mainly json payload ) of this "Does not have minimum availability" error message which can help in creating metrics for Alert.

Comment: @KhajaShaik added image to indicate where this error originates from - unsure how to traverse the JSON source. FWIW it's not exactly that important as principal question is how to alert when there isn't healthy pods.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the Step-by-Step procedure for Creating a Log Based Metric for Creating an Alert Based on it.

1. Create a [Log Based Metric](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics#getting_started) in console

   a. Go to Logging->Log Based Metric->Create Metric

   b. Select Counter in Metric type

   c. In details give any log name (ex:user/creation)

   d. In filter provide the following:

   ```
    resource.type="k8s_pod"

    severity>=WARNING 

    jsonPayload.message= "<error message>"
   ```

   You can replace the filter with something that is more appropriate for
   your case and refer this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logging-query-language) for the details of query language

   e. Let the other Fields be default

   f. Then, Create the Metric
2. Create an [Alert](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-ui) Policy :

   a. Go to Monitoring -> Alerting

   b. Select Create Policy -> Add Condition In Find Resource type and Metric
   field:

   ```
    Resource type:gke_container

    Metric:logging/user/user/creation (logging/user /<logname in step 1>) 
    (both Resource type & Metric in same field) 

    In Filter: project_id=<Your project id> 

    In configuration: Condition triggers if:All time series violate 

    Condition: is above , threshold: 0,for:most recent value
   ```

   c. Let the other fields be Default

   d. Add and click on NEXT

   e. In Notifications Channels go to Manage notifications channels this will
   redirect you to a new page in that select email->Add new (provide the
   email where you want to get notifications & display name )

   f. Refresh the previous tab now you can see your Display Name in
   Notifications channel and check the box of Display Name, Click OK

   g. Check the box of Notify on Incident Closure & Click Next

   h. Provide Alert Name & Save the Changes.

Comment: **@dzh**, did my answer help you in resolving the issue ?

Comment: **@dzh**, try to use this filter and create a log based metric

' logName="**projects/<REPLACE-THIS-WITH -PROJECTID>/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fdata_access**"
protoPayload.request.status.conditions.message:"**does not have minimumavailability.**"
protoPayload.methodName="**io.k8s.apps.v1.deployments.status.update**" '